# cant enable filestream option in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I am trying to enable the filestream option in sql server 2008 but cant seem to enable it?

When i try to enable it like in  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645585.aspx i get:

Configuration option 'filestream access level' changed from 2 to 2. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install?

Comment: Well; Have you tried running `RECONFIGURE` as suggested?

Comment: it returns : Command(s) completed successfully. When i run the create archive database script again it returns:FILESTREAM feature is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

got it working! i have to enable the filestream option for this instance first